# WordPress single-{cpt}.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

This is the php I have to generate the Custom Post Type:

```
function custom_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Products', 'rgo' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 20,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'rgo-products', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 1 );
```

And then I have a file called `single-rgo-products.php` to handle the individual single posts, but this file is not being loaded when viewing a CPT single page. I'm not even sure what template is being loaded. I've tried making changes to both the `single.php` and `index.php` files to see if changes take, and they do not.

I have tried updating the permalinks by going into settings > permalinks and saving that a couple of times.

Comment: Did you remove the `$labels` variable by mistake while editing your question or you forgot to set it up?

Comment: I removed $labels section of the code to keep it smaller when posting here, and since I was pretty sure it was irrelevant. I can post that if you think it has something to do with it. @cabrerahector

Comment: Hey @akschoeck, just copied & pasted your code (and added the `$labels` array) into Twenty Sixteen's functions.php, created a file called `single-rgo-products.php`, refreshed permalinks and things worked as expected: WordPress loaded the right template for me. Try switching to another theme and repeat what I did to see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh your permalink setting and reload the custom single page. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

the name of custom single page is wrong. Name should single+(custom post type)